Checking if aggregate frequency data is Poisson
I am stochastically modelling the number of claims per insurance policy as either Poisson (Variance = Mean) or Negative Binomial (Variance > Mean).
I'd like to do a simple check from some data if the distribution is Poisson or Negative Binomial, but the observations are based on different underlying portfolios, or aggregations, of policies, and I don't know the individual policy results. In this case, I can't work out if there is a good way to check if the mean equals the variance, or some similar check I can do for Poisson.
Suppose I have portfolios P_1, P_2,... P_n, which contain m_1, m_2,.... m_n policies in each portfolio. I know the total number of claims for each portfolio, c_1, c_2,...c_n, but I don't know them policy by policy.
I can calculate the average claims per policy as sum(c_i) / sum(m_i). I don't think though I can work out the variance on a policy level, in order to do the usual check if the variance equals the mean. Is there some other simple check around mean and variances I can do to verify that the distribution is likely Poisson? Or some other simple checks?
Thank you for reading.
